# How to circumvent basic browser XSS filtering

Tags: javascript, browser, xss, alert, netcat

I have a simple XXS attack which appears to successfully inject code into the response of the server however is filtered by browsers.  So far I have attempted Google Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.  How can I get around this?

Below is the raw client request and server response via Netcat (The injection is **bolded**):

*Request*

> GET /example.com?**0eb78">alert(1)12bbb=1 HTTP/1.1**
>   Host: example Accept: */* Accept-Language: en User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
>   Connection: close

*Response Contains*

> alert(1)12bbb=1">

However the browser url request and response are the following:

*URL Request*:

> http://example.com?0eb78">alert(1)12bbb=1

*Filtered Page Source*:

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="http://example.com?0eb78%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C/script%3E12bbb">
```

Comment: I'm having a difficult time following your question. What do you have now? what are you trying to get to? what is your goal? what is your problem? are you trying to get around the webserver removoing `<script>` from the url?

Comment: Yes Kevin that is correct, I am trying to get around the webserver removing <script> from the url.  My current problem is that I am unable to do this in the browser as shown in the "filtered page source" heading above.  My goal is to generate a dummy javascript alert in the page which I can use in a screenshot as proof of concept.

Comment: I think this is going to depend heavily on what is doing the filtering. It could be firewall, proxy, or the webserver. To get around it, you would have to somehow fool the service that is doing the filtering, disable said service, or find a way to bypass it (all three of which are pretty malicious)

Comment: Given that this filtering does not occur on my payload via a raw HTTP request, is it fair to assume that such filtering is being done client-side by the browser?  This was a major assumption of my question.

Comment: usually this kind of filtering is done on incoming requests to the server, i haven't seen it done client-side. I would guess that's a firewall, proxy, or service that sits between you and the server if that's the case. Is this a change you are doing, with say, the google console to attempt to post it to a server? or what. I would try disabling extensions too, and possibly any virus/malware protection to see what's doing the filtering.